# How to properly remove entites from OneToMany lists?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

What does it mean if one would like to remove the person from the company in the following example?

```
class Company {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company");
    List<Person> persons;
}

class Person {
    Company company;
}
```

I mean, the persons list in `Company` is always lazy fetched. Would deleting a person (from DB) mean to just remove the person entity (eg. by ID), and not having to change anything in the `persons` list of the belonging company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the person from `persons` and save the company object.

```
company.getPersons().remove(person);
```

Set the `orphanRemoval` flag if the person object should automatically be removed from the database after saving the company object. See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/index.html)  for more details.

/edit: Since you tagged the question with Hibernate the [all-delete-orphan](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html) cascade option might help you.

Comment: But wouldn't `company.getPersons()` by an empty list as ontomany is a lazy collection which is not fetched by default?

Comment: It's not "empty" in the given code. Invoking `getPersons()` causes the list to be evaluated so that the removal process works.